# Vuetify use v-html inside data table cell

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've an object with values what come from server with HTML tags like **span,p**, and I'm using vuetify data table to display this values, the problem is what I don't know how to render this HTML in table cell I know there is **v-html** directive, but how to use this directive with **vuetify**.
I found an example that modify values from specific columns:

```js
   <v-data-table
     :headers="headers"
     :items="rows"
     :search="search"
     dense>
     
     <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
       <span v-html="item.name"></span>
     </template>

   </v-data-table>
```

Here **name** is just one column, how can I use this example for each columns?

Comment: Vuetify `v-date-table` gives you slot for every header you send down. Read the docs, thera is pleanty of examples.

Comment: If you are rendering `html` tags do it in a `div` not `span`. This is a bad practice to put `p` (a block element) into a `span` (an inline-element).

Comment: I know about slot in `v-date-table`, I've tried to rewrite functionality from `tbody` without any change

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions. Create an answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that dynamically by looping through `headers` values :

```
 <v-data-table
     :headers="headers"
     :items="rows"
     :search="search"
     dense>
     
     <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:item[header.value]="{ item }">
       <div v-html="item[header.value]"></div>
     </template>

   </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried a solution with slots (see above), ESLint trows an error: "An element cannot have multiple `<template>` elements which are distributed to the same slot". To solve this problem, I used the v-simple-table instead of v-data-table and used v-html to render table data (see [codepen](https://codepen.io/myrmyr/pen/RwKgQqa?editors=101)). But be aware that v-html may be used only in cases when the table data are not modified by users, otherwise it's a possibility for an XSS attack.

```
<v-simple-table>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value" class="text-left">
              {{ header.value }}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            v-for="item in desserts"
            :key="item.name"
          >
            <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header.value" v-html="item[header.value]"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
```